# Monitors of Dell dock WD19 not working correctly after kernel upgrade

Tags: kernel, multiple-monitors, dell, 22.04, monitor

Since the last kernel upgrade on Ubuntu 22.04 (currently 5.14.0-1032-oem), my monitors plugged in a WD19 Dell dock are no longer recognized. Has anyone already faced this issue ?
I am sure the dock works fine since it has no issue with a laptop on Windows 10 plugged in.

Thanks.

Comment: IT seems to be this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1903969

Comment: The bug seems now solved for 22.04 (it alt least is on my laptop)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with dock station WD19S. It was resolved after I've installed the package linux-oem-22.04 and rebooted under the kernel 5.17.0-1016-oem. I have only one external monitor for now though.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem happened to me with Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS and DELL D3100 dock station.

Installing DisplayLink software worked perfectly.

Download driver via this [link](https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/downloads/ubuntu).
Follow [these steps](https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/684649) to install.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this can help - YMMV
anyway here is my story :
Yesterday I was able to have 2 monitors connected via displayPort<->displayPort cable to the WD19 docking station and correctly identified by my ~4 years old XPS15 laptop:
after installing the package linux-oem-22.04 (as suggested above) and a reboot
only one single monitor was identified
So I connected the second one via an HDMI<->HDMI cable directly into the laptop and... even the first one stopped working (black screen)
So I extracted the HDMI cable from the laptop and... voila`! Both monitors came back to life up and running

Not sure if this worked as some kind of soft reset of the docking station or what, but this worked for me